# Sorting a collaborative database

Tags: sorting, stata, tabulate

I'm working through a database with several repeated IDs entries and unique information per row as such

| ID | country |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | AT |
| A1 | BE |
| A2 | CZ |
| A3 | US |
| A3 | UK |
| A4 | NZ |

The same ID and different country implies there was collaboration between two different entities in this project.

How can I treat the dataset to tabulate collaborations? I would like to obtain

```
   AT BE CZ NZ US UK
AT    1
BE 1
CZ       
NZ             1  1
US           1    1  
UK           1 1


Preferably I could have the option to remove duplicates to get

   AT BE CZ NZ US UK
AT    1
BE 
CZ       
NZ             1  1
US           
UK
```

and somehow get a variable to produce 'summarize'.

Thank you in advance (I can't get access to Stata Forum due to a firewall)

I tried creating variables that identify multi-country IDs and another that reads the country when it is the second or third linked to the same ID

| ID | country | var 1 | var 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | AT |  | 1 |
| A1 | BE |  | 2 |
| A2 | CZ |  |  |
| A3 | US |  | 1 |
| A3 | UK |  | 2 |
| A4 | NZ |  | 3 |

Comment: There are discrepancies between your example data in the table and in the example in the code snippet. But I still think I understand what you mean. My answer is based on my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
clear
input str2(id country)
"A1" "AT"
"A1" "BE"
"A2" "CZ"
"A3" "US"
"A3" "UK"
"A4" "NZ"
"A4" "US"
end

* Get locals with all country abbreviation and the number of countries
levelsof country, local(countries)
local num_countries : list sizeof countries

* Collapse each project to one row where the last row has all abbreviations 
* of countries in that project. Keep only the last row for each project
sort id country
replace country = country[_n-1] + " " + country if id[_n-1] == id
by id : keep if _n == _N

* Get a local with all combination of collaborations
levelsof country, local(combos)

* Loop over each country
foreach country of local countries {
    
    * For each country get a list of collaborations that country is part of
    foreach combo of local combos {
        if strpos("`combo'","`country'") {
            local `country'_colab "``country'_colab' `combo'"
        }        
    }
    
    *Remove duplicates from list
    local `country'_colab : list uniq `country'_colab
    *Remove the country itself from that country's list
    local `country'_colab = subinstr("``country'_colab'","`country'","",.)
    *Remove all excessive spaces for no other reason than neatness
    local `country'_colab = trim(itrim("``country'_colab'"))
    
    *Display all collaborations
    di "Country `country' collaborats with countries: ``country'_colab'"
}

* Clear the original data and create a new data set with one obs per country
clear
set obs `num_countries'

* Create one row and row column for each country. 
* Set the default to 0 for no collaboration
gen country = ""
local row = 1
foreach country of local countries {
    gen `country' = 0
    replace country = "`country'" if _n == `row++'
}

* Go over the list of collaborations for each country and set value to 1
* where the row and column country collaborates
foreach country of local countries {
    foreach colab of local `country'_colab {
        replace `colab' = 1 if country == "`country'"
    }
}
```

I have not cleared duplicates as you suggested as a preference as I think you get an ambivalent data set as it is not clear for which country you should drop a row and for which you should drop a column.